# Whonix tor downloader never works for me. It says its an app and not in the (/.tb) folder?

Tags: whonix

The default tor downloader for me never works. I always have to end up manually installing. Is this normal? Or a sign that I'm compromised? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not normal, but also not a sign for being compromised. See:

[Am I compromised?](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/FAQ#Am_I_compromised.3F)

Debugging your tb-updater issue is not suited for stackexchange, because'd have to provide debug output, answer back and forth several times. If you want to like this out, please post in https://forums.whonix.org.